# database connection issue while installing PIM community edition

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pim

I am trying to install the PIM community edition when I give NO_DOCKER=true make dev command everything gos well but at the end i am getting bellow message. Please help in resolving this issue. I have already created database and user as well on DB

Database does not exist yet

13:53:31 CRITICAL  [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists=1 --no-debug=1 --env=dev". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution" ["exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException^ { …},"command" => "doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists=1 --no-debug=1 --env=dev","message" => "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution"]

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary fa
ilure in name resolution

In PDOConnection.php line 31:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

In PDOConnection.php line 27:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

In PDOConnection.php line 27:

PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

The command terminated with an error code: 1.

In CommandExecutor.php line 66:

The command terminated with an error code: 1.

doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

Makefile:57: recipe for target 'database' failed
make[2]: *** [database] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/srv/pim'
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'pim-dev' failed
make[1]: *** [pim-dev] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/srv/pim'
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'dev' failed
make: *** [dev] Error 2